# com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databand upgraded to latest 2.14.2 version, yet application war shows vulnerabilities

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind, cve

I'm using 6.9.2 version for gradle wrapper and my application war file is flagged with the following Jackson-databand vulnerabilities CVE-2022-42004, CVE-2022-42003, CVE-2020-36518, CVE-2022-25649 in WIZ Security scanning.

To solve this I have upgraded the old vulnerable version 2.10.0 to the latest one 2.14.2 in build.gradle and excluded the jackson-databind module from some of the implementations but final scan results not of much luck.
Even after the upgrade, wiz scan shows vulnerability with old 2.10.0 version, although when I checked inside the war file, it shows 2.14.2 version for jackson-databind jar.

Can you please help me?
I fail to understand what's going wrong.

For reference find a screenshot of how I upgraded using gradle constraints and excluded the module, along with the final dependency tree.
[Dependency constraints added for jackson-databind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PivdE.jpg)
[Module exclusions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHdH3.jpg)